# Matlab - Cell arrays and giving variable name with different indexes

Tags: matlab, for-loop, cell-array

I'm trying to make a `for-loop` in `matlab` that would return the following:

```
C_1 = 0
C_2 = 0
C_3 = 0
C_4 = 0
C_5 = 0
```

But, *before* that, I want also a value as follows: `C_0 = 0`.

I gave it a try as follows but didn't work:

```
function test
    C{0} = 0;
    for i=1:5
        C{i} = 0
    end
end
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is zero based indexing available in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239907/is-zero-based-indexing-available-in-matlab)

Comment: Just an observation: though you cannot use `C{0}`, you can in fact use `for i=0:5` so would not need to separate the two cases.

Comment: please delete this question as you have already duplicated it into a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer:
You can't use `C{0}`

The simple workaround:

Increase all indices by 1,
use `C{1}` to `C{6}` instead of `C{0}` to `C{5}`

For the complex answer, look at the link given by @Oli