# Matlab: how to redefine indexing to begin from zero? `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.`

Tags: matlab, error-handling, indexing, bigdata, readability

I have a mathematical data where it would be very convenient to have the index to start from zero like

```
a=sparse([],[],[],30,1);
>> a(0)=someValueHere
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

but Matlab by default offers only the index to start from 1. Is there some easy hack or trick by which I could still assign `a(0)` so that I don't need to create a dummyVar `a0` for the value or append the value at the end?

**So how to get assignment such as `a(0)` in Matlab? Every time zero-index called catch the error and return someValueHere instead of the warning?**

Comment: Please, explain downvoting -- there must be some hack to get this working. I see no reason for not to: catch the error and redefine the assignment.

Comment: Very funny. `a(i+1)`?

Comment: @horchler Pardon. Trolling?

Comment: this is like asking how to redefine indexing in C to begin from, say, 42... I vote to close.

Comment: Not at all. With `a(i+1)` now `i` can start at `0`. I don't know what other solution you might be looking for. Maybe write a mex function to use C's 0 indexing? I'm not sure you've explained your issue, which certainly can be solved using Matlab's indexing.

Comment: @natan I see it as an error-handling question but I am not sure whether it is a proper solution -- other solution is to create a dummy var -- not knowing which better alternative to get the zero index.

Comment: @horchler it is not a realistic solution for me because I am playing with binaries -- the zero index refers to specific monomial here constant and `0001` refers to a specific monomial also. Changing index numbers by one asks for problems, confusing things unnecessarily.

Comment: consider the possibility that your assignment might require that you start some variable 0, but not require that you index from 0.

Comment: @natan I find it confusing. My partner solves this problem by declaring a dummy var A0 but I find it unnecessarily cluttered (it would require changing all functions with one extra parameter). I am trying to find a solution that would not require changing the indexing, far better for readability. I have large amount of vars such as 31 vars where each var correspond to a bit in binary so adding +1 to all indexing would require a larger data-structure by one-bit, err...not wanting one-bit longer data-structure...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is zero based indexing available in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239907/is-zero-based-indexing-available-in-matlab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get MATLAB's index to start from 0 you'll need to make an large set of object classes that emulate regular numeric classes, but behave differently with functions such as `subsassgn()`, `subsref()`  etc.

Maybe someone was crazy enough to do it somewhere, I'd expect this to take weeks to months of work to actually work properly.

Answer (score 3):

There is a discussion on the matlab index issue: http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/285566

Maybe you can write a function like

```
function t=C_index(x)
  t = x + 1;
```

Then you can write something like y(C_index(0)) to get the first value in vector y.

In Addition,

```
t=@(x) x+1
y(t(0))
```

should work.

Comment: you can also do this using anonymous functions. see my edit to your answer.

Comment: @natan thanks for your reminder, i was just about to update :)

Comment: This would require changing all index-things to `t(...)`, I still find it easier to catch the warning and then store the `a(0)` to something so that the user can use it like `a(0)`. Is this best created with some class or something?

Comment: @hhh: With your strategy iterating and vectorisation will be a mess.

Comment: @hhh I agree with Daniel R.