# Fibonacci function not accepting 0 and not displaying the last term only

Tags: matlab, while-loop, fibonacci

I wrote a function that displays the Fibonacci sequence up to the nth term. The code runs fine, but I want to make two changes and am not sure how to do so.

Here is my code:

```
function [ F ] = get_fib( k )
    F(1) = 1;
    F(2) = 1;
    i = 3;

    while k >= i;
        F(i) = F(i-1) + F(i-2);
        i = i + 1;
    end
end
```

The first problem is that the code does not accept `0` as an input. I tried changing the function to:

```
function [ F ] = get_fib( k )
    F(0) = 0;
    F(1) = 1;
    F(2) = 1;
    i = 3;

    while k >= i;
        F(i) = F(i-1) + F(i-2);
        i = i + 1;
    end
end
```

But the following error appears:

> Attempted to access F(0); index must be a positive integer or logical.
>
> Error in get_fib (line 2) 
>   F(0) = 0;

I would also like the code to display the last term in the sequence, rather than the entire sequence.

I changed the function to:

```
function [ F ] = get_fib( k );
    F(1) = 1;
    F(2) = 1;
    i = 3;

    while k >= i;
        F(i) = F(i-1) + F(i-2);
        i = i + 1;
    end

    term = F(k)
end
```

but the sequence it still being assigned to `ans`.

*How can I make my function accept `0` as an argument and only display the last term of the sequence?*

Answer (score 0):

First let's get your function to output just the last item in the sequence. You're setting `term` like this:

```
term = F(k);
```

Which is good (notice I added the ; at the end, though). But the return value from your function is `F`. You need to change it to `term`.

```
function [ term ] = get_fib( k )
     %//   ^^^^- change this    ^-- semicolon not necessary here
```

Now, to handle an input of `0`, you can add a special check for zero:

```
function [ term ] = get_fib( k )
   if k == 0
      term = [];
      return;
   end

   while k >= i
       %//     ^-- semicolon not needed here, either
   <the rest of your code>
```

The semicolons after the function header and the `while` statement don't hurt anything, they just represent empty statements. But they might be misleading, so it's best to remove them.

The semicolon after the assignment to `term` prevents the `ans = ...` line from printing out to the console.

Answer (score 0):

To address your first problem, `F(0)` is not a valid call. This is because MATLAB indexing starts from 1. In other words, the first element of a matrix is index 1. There is no 0th index of a matrix in MATLAB. [See here for why MATLAB indexing starts from 1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239907/is-zero-based-indexing-available-in-matlab) What I would recommend to address this is to shift your output array by one index.

Thus, your code for the function should be:

```
function [ F ] = get_fib( k )
k = k + 1
F(1) = 0;    % 0th Fibonacci term
F(2) = 1;    % 1st Fibonacci term
F(3) = 1;    % 2nd Fibonacci term
i = 4;

while k >= i
    F(i) = F(i-1) + F(i-2);
    i = i + 1;
end
   term = F(k)
end
```

To address your second problem, it would depend on what you want. Do you (1) want the last term in the sequence to be returned when you call `term = get_fib(k)`or (2) want the last term of the sequence to be displayed and the entire sequence to be returned?

To achieve (1), fix the top line of your code to `function term = F(k)`. To achieve (2), call the function with `F = get_fib(some_number)`, as @rayryeng stated.

Answer (score 0):

Since others already pointed out how to fix your code, I'd like to show you one approach to calculate the *nth* Fibonacci number without relying on the *F(n-1)* and *F(n-2)* terms calculation.

It involves the golden ratio, and you can read more about its relationship to the Fibonacci sequence [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_sequence).

```
function [ F ] = get_fib( n )
    % Changed your input variable from k to n (standard notation)    
    Phi = (1+sqrt(5))/2; % Golden ratio value
    F = round((Phi^n - ((-1)^n)/(Phi^n))/sqrt(5)); %nth fibonacci number

end
```

Since you are only interested in the last value of the sequence, it could speed up the calculation for large values of *n*.

Note i have rounded the output (`F`) to avoid floating point arithmetic errors.