# Euler's and Fibonacci's approximation in script

Tags: matlab, fibonacci, eulers-number

I have written two function in Matlab; one solves for the factorial of the input and the other solves for the nth term of the Fibonacci sequence. I'm now trying to make a script for each function - one to calculate Euler's number to 10 decimals and the other to calculate the reciprocal Fibonacci number to 10 decimals.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Vx2.png)

I have created the following two functions for the factorial and Fibonacci sequence, respectively.

```
function [ nfactorial ] = get_fact( n )
%input a non-negative integer
%output is factorial of that integer
for i=0:n
    nfactorial=prod(1:n);
end
```

and

```
function [ F ] = get_fib( k )

if k < 0
    fprintf('positive integer please')
end

k = k + 1;
F(1) = 0;    % 0th Fibonacci term
F(2) = 1;    % 1st Fibonacci term
F(3) = 1;    % 2nd Fibonacci term
i = 4;

while k >= i
    F(i) = F(i-1) + F(i-2);
    i = i + 1;
end
   F = F(k)
end
```

How would I go about putting these in scripts?

I tried:

```
for i = 0:n
    e = prod(1 / get_fact( i ))
end
```

But this returned errors and obviously has no tolerance set so if it did work, it would be infinite. I have never put a function into a script so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you attend the course which gave you this matlab homework? There are some serious semantic issues with your code.

Comment: Yes I am there every class. An example of a function or script was never shown in class... yet this was assigned.

Comment: Well, *syntactically* your functions would work fine, so would your script call. The problem is that *what those functions are doing is wrong on multiple levels*. So: if you're there on every class, do they ever teach you something? And if they teach you something, do you ever learn something? **Hint**: if your loop over `i` doesn't contain any `i`, then you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Like I said, I was never taught how to do this. So obviously it will have flaws which is why I am asking for advice. No need to be condescending.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to be condescending. My grumpyness is mostly directed at your teacher, as you should not make such mistakes if you were taught properly. Really, I didn't mean to offend you, and sorry for coming across this way.

Comment: Technical note: I see you've made use of [the answers to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046312/while-loop-help-please). On behalf of the others: please consider marking one of those answers as accepted, if they were the ones solving your problem. Also: "this returned errors" is never enough, you should always include the error messages to help us debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your functions, and calling your functions is fine in each case. Your functions, on the other hand, have some semantic problems.

In `get_fact`:

```
function [ nfactorial ] = get_fact( n )
%input a non-negative integer
%output is factorial of that integer
for i=0:n
    nfactorial=prod(1:n);
end
```

`prod(1:n)` will multiply the numbers from `1` to `n`, see `help :` and `help prod`. So it exactly calculates the factorial by itself! No need to have a loop over `i`: you'll just compute the same thing over and over again. On a more serious note: `get_fact(0)` will give you 0, which it shouldn't. Prepare your function for this case!

In `get_fib`:

```
function [ F ] = get_fib( k )

if k < 0
    fprintf('positive integer please')
end

k = k + 1;
F(1) = 0;    % 0th Fibonacci term
F(2) = 1;    % 1st Fibonacci term
F(3) = 1;    % 2nd Fibonacci term
i = 4;

while k >= i
    F(i) = F(i-1) + F(i-2);
    i = i + 1;
end
   F = F(k)
end
```

you print a message if `k<0`, but you don't do anything extra afterwards. This should be an error message of sorts, so you should either use `error` instead of `fprintf`, or write `F=NaN; return` after `fprintf` to prematurely return from the function (without an official error). Otherwise this function seems fine to me.

Now, if you save `get_fact` into `get_fact.m` and `get_fib` into `get_fib.m` somewhere on your MATLAB path (which always includes the current directory), you can call them as `get_fact(3)` and similar for `get_fib()` as you tried.

But your call is also problematic:

```
for i = 0:n
    e = prod(1 / get_fact( i ))
end
```

here you would call again `e = prod(1 / get_fact( i ))` for each `i`, *in each step overwriting `e`*. You obviously don't want this. You should either define a vector in place of `e` and sum its contents in the end, or keep incrementing the value of your scalar `e` in each iteration (but then you have to initialize it to 0). And `prod(1/get_fact(i))` will just give you `1/get_fact(i)` since this quantity is a scalar. You would need a sum in any way, and you would have to do it in a different way (see a few sentences earlier).

The tolerance your teacher speaks about is related to the cut-off of the loop where you increment the value of `e`, i.e. the approximation to the infinite sum. First you can just take a given maximum order of the approximation, and if it works as it should then you can work on implementing the tolerance.