# Overload operator on Matlab dataset array

Tags: matlab, oop, dataset, operator-overloading

Following [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365464/matlab-is-it-possible-to-overload-operators-on-native-constructs-cells-struct), I set out to do something similar for datasets.

The `plus` function mentioned in that answer, I got working fine for cell arrays by putting the plus.m in an @cell-folder.
However on trying the exact same (slightly different implementation) in a @dataset-folder, Matlab still gives an "undefined" error for both `Dataset+Dataset` and `plus(Dataset,Dataset)`.

What am I getting wrong?

#### Edit 1

In the current directory, there is the folder @dataset (same place as the working @cell folder), containing the file plus.m containing the code:

```
function C = plus(A,B)
% assuming same size, valid type, etc.
C = zeros(size(A));
for i = 1:size(A,2)
    C(:,i) = A.(i) + B.(i);
end
end
```

In the command prompt, try:

```
ds = dataset({1,'a'},{2,'b'});
ds+ds
```

Matlab throws the error:
`Undefined function 'plus' for input arguments of type 'dataset'.`

#### Edit 2

*Summary of workarounds*

The short version is Daniels answer below. A write-up of the alternative options can be found [here](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=4776). In short, they present the options below (for overloading functions in general - not all solutions will allow the use of a standard operator such as '+' - here described for the present issue). None of them *solves* my problem, but could be used as workarounds.

1. Define a new function that takes the desired class as arguments -- ala `dsplus(ds,ds)`
2. Define a new `plus` function, in which you catch and handle classes that you want to implement functionality for, and reroute others to the built-in.
3. Daniels suggestion.
4. Make a new `mydataset` class inheriting from from `dataset` (`classdef mySym < sym`)
5. Make a new `mydataset` class using composition (i.e. include the built-in `dataset` as a property of the `mydataset` class)

I would add a 6.th option: Leave Matlab and learn Python. An option that by the day looks increasingly appealing.

Comment: Ckeck your usage of CaPiTaLs... Dataset vs. dataset

Comment: Can you give us enough information to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Nick The `Dataset` in above ware intended as variable names (ala MyDataset) being of type dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to extend a class by defining methods in a different @-folder is a feature of [the old object object system](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/pre-version_7.6_oop.pdf), the one based on [struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) (pre MATLAB 7.6).

The current OOP system (`classdef`-style) does not support this, since @-folders will shadow other @-folders with the same name (according to which one appears first on the path).

Now `cell` (which is a builtin type/class) is apparently based on the old system, since you can define a `@cell/plus.m` function anywhere on the path and it works.

However `dataset` is a class defined in the new system (`classdef`) so you cannot extend it that way, unless of course you place your function inside the toolbox's own directory (you'll need to `rehash` the toolbox path afterwards for it to take effect).

```
>> which dataset
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\shared\statslib\@dataset\dataset.m
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is not clear to me, but this is likely the intended behaviour. The first thing to realize is that the `cell` and `dataset` classes are different. The `dataset` class is defined in an @-folder and `dataset.m` begins with `classdef`. Between R2008a, when the `classdef` OO system was introduced, and R2012a the documentation read:

> Only One @-Folder per Class
>
> For classes defined using the new classdef keyword, an @-folder
>   shadows all @-folders that occur after it on the MATLAB path. Classes
>   defined in @-folders must locate all class files in that single
>   folder. However, classes defined in @-folders continue to take
>   precedence over functions and scripts having the same name, even those
>   function and scripts that come before them on the path.

In R2012b (i.e., MATLAB 8.0) the documentation changed to:

> Previous Behavior of Classes Defined in @-Folders
>
> In MATLAB Versions 5 through 7, @-folders do not shadow other
>   @-folders having the same name, but residing in later path folders.
>   Instead, the class is defined by the combination of methods from all
>   @-folders having the same name. This is no longer true.
>
> Note that for backward compatibility, classes defined in @-folders
>   always take precedence over functions and scripts having the same
>   name, even those that come before them on the path.

I have now read the documentation a number of times and I still have no idea what changed between R2012a and R2012b. None of this applies to the `cell` class since it is not defined in an `@folder`.