# How to reset @class folder to native state

Tags: matlab, oop

I have inadvertently messed around with my `matlabroot` folder and now some functionality is broken. How do I reset the state of the folder so that everything works again?

While trying to solve this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602298/add-a-method-to-matlab-table-class/34603252?noredirect=1#comment56953104_34603252), I added a new method (`nansubset.m`) to the `@table` folder (`[matlabroot,'\toolbox\matlab\datatypes\@table\*']`). That did not work so I deleted it and moved it to my Matlab path as suggested by @TroyHaskin's answer. Everything worked fine until I restarted Matlab. Now I am getting the error message:

```
Error using table/nansubset
Previously accessible file "C:\Program
Files\MATLAB\R2015b\toolbox\matlab\datatypes\@table\nansubset.m" is now inaccessible.
```

I have tried `clear classes` and `clear java` and restarting Matlab, to no avail.

EDIT:
I also found [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/156395) on the Mathworks site, which led me to `doc toolbox_path_cache` that in turn suggests using `rehash toolboxcache`. I did this and now there is a new error message:

```
Error using table/nansubset
Method 'nansubset' is not defined for class 'table' or is removed from MATLAB's search path.
```

However, `which nansubset` returns the right file from a directory on my Matlab path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem. Essentially, following the instructions from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/156395), we are led to the [helpfile](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/toolbox-path-caching-in-the-matlab-program.html) for `toolbox_path_cache`, which states:

> When you add or remove files in matlabroot/toolbox folders by some
>   other means, MATLAB might not recognize those changes.
>
> ...
>
> Update the cache so MATLAB recognizes
>   the changes you made in matlabroot/toolbox folders.

To update the cache, type `rehash toolbox` and `rehash toolboxcache`. After this, it was necessary to restart Matlab to fix the problem