# Is it possible to add methods to containers.Map class in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, oop, containers

I'm trying to add a method to the `containers.Map` class, for example

```
function sayHello(obj)
    disp('Hello!')
end
```

And I want to be able to do:

```
map = containers.Map('Foo', 'Bar');
map.sayHello
```

I've added `sayHello.m` to `/my/path/+containers/@Map`, but `methods containers.Map` and `which -all sayHello` both don't find my method.

What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to add methods to this class?

Thanks

Comment: It may not be possible to add methods to a built-in class, but you should be able to subclass it.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas, but I have managed to add methods (in the way described in my question) to `cell`, `char` and `fints` - just not `containers.Map`.

Comment: Because `containers.Map` is relatively new (R2008b compared to the other classes you listed), it probably falls under different method overloading rules as [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602298/add-a-method-to-matlab-table-class/34603252#34603252) and needs to be sub-classed for extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this looks to not be possible. Rubbish.

[See also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602298/add-a-method-to-matlab-table-class/34603252#34603252).