# Is there a way to make Matlab ints behave more like C++ ints?

Tags: matlab, integer-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get real integer overflows in MATLAB/Octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425251/how-do-i-get-real-integer-overflows-in-matlab-octave)

I'm writing a Matlab routine that would help me simulate something I will eventually code in C++. One problem is that Matlab and C++ ints behave differently when performing arithmetic operations that cause produce results larger than the container can hold.

For example, in Matlab `intmax('uint16')` produces `65535`. And `intmax('uint16')+1` still produces `65535`. If you want to go higher than 65535, you can't. Matlab simply puts a cap on it.

C++ is different. Writing `unsigned short x = 65535; cout << ++x;` produces `0` because it performs the addition fully and simply keeps 16 least significant bits.

Is there a way of making Matlab behave the same way?

Comment: Take a look over to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425251/how-do-i-get-real-integer-overflows-in-matlab-octave . I like the overload function method.