# Find the largest x for which x^b+a = a

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

[Stability (Numerical analysis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276737/matlab-numerical-analysis-stability-the-largest-x-for-which-x-a-a)

Trying to apply the answer I saw in this question, `a+x=a` worked just fine with `a+eps(a)/2`. Suppose we have `x^b+a=a`, where `b` is a small integer, say 3 and `a=2000`. Then `a+(eps(a))^3` or `a+(eps(a)/2)^3` will always return number `a`. Can someone help with the measurement of `x`? Any way, even different from eps will do just fine.

p.s. `1938+(eps(1938)/0.00000000469)^3` is the last number that returns `ans = 1.9380e+003`. 
`1938+(eps(1938)/0.0000000047)^3` returns `a=1938`. Does that have to do with anything?

Comment: It look like a digit rounding problem ? Can you clarify your question, you want help to know why using epsilon ? Or something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x = (eps(a)/2).^(1/(b-eps(a)/2))`

if `b = 3`,

```
(eps(1938)/2).^(1/(3-eps(1938)/2)) > eps(1938)/0.0000000047
```

Comment: a=1938;
b=3;
x = (eps(a)/2).^(1/b)
x =

  4.8444e-005
 a+x^3

ans =

  1.9380e+003
I need a+x^3 to be sharply 1938. It would work for b=5, but not for b=3. Any suggestions? (Sorry for bad formatting, I'm only new in stackoverflow)

Comment: try x=(eps(a)/2).^(1/(b-eps(a)/2))   , I updated the answer as well, thx