# Hide lines of code in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to know If it's possible and how, to hide some parts of a line or whole lines of code from a script in MATLAB. For example:

```
if a=b
   x=y+1; x=x^2;
end
```

And have the x=x^2 hidden, but still run the process. I mean:

```
if a=b
       x=y+1; 
end
```

Comment: if you use windows, CTRL+R for commenting, CTRL+T for uncommenting

Comment: Are you talking about hiding it but still running it? If so, WHY?

Comment: Do you want to hide `x=x^2` and still want  `x=x^2` to execute? I hope that's not what you're asking! :D but if you still want that, you can make a function and call that instead of  `x=x^2`.  Other than that, you need two *equals to* signs in `if` . i.e `if a==b`

Comment: Yes, ofc if a==b (that was a mistake and an example). I want to make exactly that, but I mean not to be seen. I want to make a joke to a friend of mine, but he could spot the difference because he knows how to code. The function would be visible, so that won't work. Thanks again!

Comment: http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/698/489/2f7.png

Answer (score 6):

*(wringing hands with evil grin on face)*

If you **really** want to mess with people like this, you're going to want to go down the [operator overloading route](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-operators-for-your-class.html). Come with me on a journey where you will almost certainly shoot yourself in the foot while trying to play a joke on someone else!

*(lightning crackles over the laughter of a madman)*

I've discussed this in a few other questions before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5365464/52738) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2425251/52738)). Basically, you can change the default behavior of built-in operators for MATLAB data types. In this case, we'll change how the [`plus`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plus.html) operator works for variables of class [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) (the default variable type). Make a folder called `@double` on your [MATLAB path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html), then create a file called `plus.m` and put the following code inside it:

```
function C = plus(A, B)

  C = builtin('plus', A, B);

  if strcmp(inputname(1), 'y')
    C = C.^2;
  end

end
```

Now, try it for yourself...

```
>> y=1;   % Initialize y
>> x=y+1
x =
     4    % Wait a minute...
>> x=1+1
x =
     2    % OK
>> x=1+y
x =
     2    % OK
>> x=y+1
x =
     4    % What?!
>> x=y+2;
x = 
     9    % No!!
>> y=3;
>> x=y+1
x =
    16    % Oh noes! I've been hax0red!!11!1!
```

**How it works:**

The new `plus` function shadows the built-in one, so it gets called when performing addition on doubles. It first invokes the built-in `plus` to do the actual addition using the [`builtin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html) function. This is necessary, because if you wrote `C=A+B;` here it would call the phony `plus` again and cause infinite recursion. Then, it uses the [`inputname`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html) function to check what the variable name of the first input to the function is. If it's `'y'`, we square the result before returning it.

Have fun!!!

...and remember to remove it when you're done. ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
if a==b
    x = y+1;
    for ind = 1
        x = x^2;
    end
end
```

Bit of a wacky way, but you can collapse `loop/end` blocks like `for` and `while` loops. Simply click the `-` sign in the editor:

[image]

So for two or less lines this doesn't help you, but if you want to hide e.g. 40 lines, it shortens it appreciably.

Another option is to simply chuck in a hundred or so spaces and make it obfuscated:

```
if a==b
    x = y+1;                                                                                                                                          x = x^2;
end
```

Thanks to [excaza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2748311/excaza) the most obfuscated way of all to write `x=x^2;`:

```
eval(cast((sscanf('240,122,240,188,100,118', '%d,')./2)', 'like', ''))
```

Comment: I think I found a slightly more obfuscated way. >:)