# How to disable Matlab Integer Overflow saturation to get signed wraparound

Tags: matlab, integer-overflow

I want to test a piece of function and from 127, it is normal for me that 127+1 = -128. But for Matlab, it saturates my value even though it is a desired behavior on my code.

There are explanations to disable this option on Simulink but what about for a script? I don't know how to disable this feature.

Comment: I suggest you use one of the answer to this question: [How do I get real integer overflows in MATLAB/Octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425251/how-do-i-get-real-integer-overflows-in-matlab-octave)

Answer (score 1):

Overflow is not part of Matlab hypotheses.
You need to implement this behaviour in your script using [the modulo function (mod)](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html).
For example:

```
>> a=127; mod(a+128,256)-128

ans =

   127

>> a=128; mod(a+128,256)-128

ans =

  -128
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use 127 and -128 as the examples, I assume you are working with int8 variable types. To get the modulo behavior you want, you could use a simple C mex routine to do the arithmetic (since your C compiler will in all likelihood optimize this overflow condition away as simple modulo behavior), or in m-code you can convert to a larger type and do the arithmetic yourself (assumes your machine uses 2's complement storage for integer types). E.g.,

```
a8 = int8(127); % sample data
b8 = int8(1); % sample data
a16 = int16(a8); % convert to larger type
b16 = int16(b8); % convert to larger type
c16 = a16 + b16 % do the addition in larger type
    c16 = int16
        128
c8s = typecast(c16,'int8') % typecast back to int8 (assume 2's complement storage)
    c8s = 1x2
       -128    0
c8 = c8s(1) % pick either c8s(1) or c8s(2) depending on endian of your machine
    c8 = int8
       -128
```

If you are working with arrays of numbers instead of scalars, then you could put this in a loop or vectorize the last line as either c8s(1:2:end) or c8s(2:2:end)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [fi](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/embedded.fi.html) object from [Fixed-Point toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/fixed-point-designer.html) and set `OverflowAction` to `Wrap`.

Using `fi` for applying `int8` type that overflows, is a bit of an overkill, but possible.

Example:

```
x = fi(127, true, 8, 0, 'OverflowAction', 'Wrap', 'SumMode', 'SpecifyPrecision', 'SumWordLength', 8, 'SumFractionLength', 0);

x + 1
```

Output:

```
ans = 

  -128

          DataTypeMode: Fixed-point: binary point scaling
            Signedness: Signed
            WordLength: 8
        FractionLength: 0

        RoundingMethod: Nearest
        OverflowAction: Wrap
           ProductMode: FullPrecision
               SumMode: SpecifyPrecision
         SumWordLength: 8
     SumFractionLength: 0
         CastBeforeSum: true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the `int8` overflow and not simulate it with the `mod` function, you can use the [typecast](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) function.

First, you need to convert your variable into an `int` (otherwise it is by default a `double` in Matlab). Then you cast it to an `int8` and you keep only the first byte:

```
>> a=127; getfield(typecast(int64(a),'int8'),{1})

ans =

  int8

   127

>> a=128; getfield(typecast(int64(a),'int8'),{1})

ans =

  int8

   -128
```